# How to let the Hyper-V / Virtual Machine Connection window use native resolution instead of incorrect high-DPI scaling?

Tags: windows-8.1, virtualization, hyper-v, high-dpi

I installed Ubuntu 14.04 on a Hyper-V virtual machine hosted on Windows 8.1. It all runs on a Surface 3, so the high DPI scaling is enabled on Windows.

I also have a plain old full HD secondary display attached to the Surface.

Now, I managed to get my Ubuntu installation use a 1920x1080 resolution, but it does not look correct on my 1080p secondary display.

This how it works:

- If I drag the Hyper-V/Virtual Machine Connection window to the **Surface
  high-res display**, *the picture is sharp but small, and one pixel in
  Ubuntu equals to one physical pixel on the Surface display*.
- When I drag it to the **1080p secondary display** *the whole thing is
  scaled down* so that the window sizes would rougly match that on the
  Surface. As a result *the Ubuntu screen is blury and small*.

This is the exact opposite of what should happen:

- On the **Surface display,** the Ubuntu screen should preferably be scaled up
- More importantly, on the **secondary display**, the *Ubuntu screen should match the physical pixels* and use all the real-estate when in full screen mode

*Any ideas on what is going wrong here with the scaling, and how I could fix it?*

Answer (score 0):

You can try setting the compatibility flags directly in the registry which are at the following registry location:

`HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\AppCompatFlags\Layers`

In that key, create a (string) entry as such:

- Name: `C:\Windows\System32\vmconnect.exe`
- Type: `REG_SZ` (String)
- Data: `~HIGHDPIAWARE`